# Use onShowFileChooser with Google Drive API

Tags: android, webview, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

Is it possible to implementing file chooser with google drive API?

I've tried this code but I have no idea what to do next.

This one is my Web Chrome Client :

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                    WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                    WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {

                Log.d(TAG, "CHOOSE FILE SHOW");
                mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;

                IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                        .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
                        .build(getGoogleApiClient());
                try {
                    startIntentSenderForResult(
                            intentSender, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE, null, 0, 0, 0);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Unable to send intent", e);
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
```

This one is the activity result :

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        return;
    }

    Uri[] results;

    // Check that the response is a good one
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        DriveId driveId = data.getParcelableExtra(
                OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);
        HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        com.google.api.services.drive.Drive mService = new com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Builder(
                transport, jsonFactory, mCredential)
                .setApplicationName("Drive API Android Quickstart")
                .build();
        try {
            File file = mService.files().get(driveId.getResourceId()).execute();
            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(file.getDownloadUrl())};
            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mFilePathCallback = null;
    }
}
```

The next question is, how to get the file from driveId? Should I use the API one?

Comment: If you'll be letting your users can access and upload photos, videos, maps, and documents stored in Google servers. Try checking the  [intent](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos) to see how it is used. Also try checking Google sample application: QuickEditor — A sample text editor application, demonstrating various API features in a real-world scenario. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot Thank you for your reply, sir. Yup, I've already read that. But what I really want is an example how to get a file via download from the driveId.